# Bitwise shift precision

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to port a Python library to Javascript, but stumbled on a numerical difference between the two..

With Python, 1057618395136 >> 16 == 16137976
With Javascript, 1057618395136 >> 16 == 16120

I read the the integer precision in Javascript is 53 bits, Math.pow(2, 53) == 9007199254740991), which is still in the range of the bifshift operation im trying to do.. What am i missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JavaScript bitwise operators truncate the floating-point values down to 32-bit integers. Thus, though it is true that a 64-bit floating point value can hold 53-bit integers, you cannot take advantage of all 53 bits with shift operators.

To shift right by 16 bits in JavaScript, you can divide by 65536.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense!
Out of curiosity (i know such micro optimizations are neglectable), is there a difference in performance between the bitshift and the division?

Comment: @Martijnh well it's possible that the JavaScript runtime recognizes the fact that you're dividing by a constant that's a power of 2. Most modern hardware (aside from low-end phones) can probably do 64-bit shift operations. Whether any actual implementations do that, I don't know.